# Cursor getting stuck after splitting windows horizontally

Tags: window-splitting

Recently I have started to split my Emacs windows horizontally. However, when I do this, moving the cursor down frequently raises the following error:

```
posn-col-row: Wrong type argument: windowp, #<frame buffer/file-name 0x11756e8>
```

And the cursor will be stuck wherever it is. In the example below, as soon as I hit the dollar sign/newline (I have `whitespace-mode` enabled to help myself with diagnosis) I can no longer move the cursor down (although I can always move left and right).

[image]

The stranger thing, is that if I have a horizontal split with two windows and the same buffer in each window, then the problem only happens in the window on the right...It seems to only happen when I have `visual-line-mode` disabled - but I have disabled it in certain modes precisely because `visual-line-mode` seems to do weird things when the window is too narrow, so I would prefer a fix that doesn't involve enabling visual-line-mode. Any suggestions? Thank you!

## Update:

This problem was occurring on my work computer, and I just tried to recreate it on my home computer. My configuration is synced through github, so I thought everything was exactly the same, but I just remembered that the version of Emacs I am using at work (the one with the problem) is the one from the Ubuntu repositories, while the one I am using at home (which doesn't seem to have a problem) was compiled from source and is a newer version.

Knowing this, I will do some more debugging on Monday when I get back to my work computer, and maybe just get a more recent version of Emacs.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Emacs, I would suggest sending a bug report. If possible, include a step-by-step guide on how to reproduce the errror.

Comment: What @Lindydancer said. `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Are there any third-party major/minor modes that are active in the visible windows that use `posn-col-row`?  [A grep for that function in the `.emacs.d` folder and inside the `.emacs` file may be helpful.]  If not already done, you can enable debugging with: `(setq debug-on-error t)`  If this just started happening recently and you didn't upgrade or install a new version of Emacs, then the user-configuration and third-party installed libraries would be the most likely source of the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this issue on my work computer, and once I got home, I tested it out on my home computer, which uses the same init file. No problems at all! This made things even more confusing for me, until I remembered that I was running an older version (`24.4`) on my work computer than on my home computer (running `24.5`).

Today I installed Emacs 24.5 on my work computer following the super-easy instructions in the answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437255/how-to-install-emacs-24-4-on-ubuntu) question. After that, I no longer have this issue, and everything works fine with horizontal and vertical window splits! I am not going to bother submitting a bug report, because it seems to have been fixed in the most recent version of Emacs.